# AppleScript and SuperCard

Tags: applescript

The following script works

```
tell application "System Events"
  set XXX to (list disks)
  if "Samsung_T1" is in XXX then
    tell application "SuperCard"
      beep
      --send mouseUp to cd button "Samsung_T1"
    end tell
  end if
end tell
```

but the next one does not

```
tell application "System Events"
  set XXX to (list disks)
  if "Samsung_T1" is in XXX then
    tell application "SuperCard"
      beep
      send mouseUp to cd button "Samsung_T1"
    end tell
  end if
end tell
```

Why?

I tried changing it using globals but to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

MARK LUCAS

Mar 10, 2024, 12:00:31 AM (yesterday)

to via SuperCard Discussion
Remember to keep your scripting dialects separate:

tell application "SuperCard 4.8" to do script "beep" & return & "send mouseUp to cd button "Samsung_T1""